# Indian National Olympiad $2002$, Problem $6$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

> Suppose the $n^{2}$ numbers $1,2,3, \ldots, n^{2}$ are arranged to form an $n$ by $n$ array consisting of $n$ rows and $n$ columns such that the numbers in each row (from left to right) and each column(from top to bottom) are in increasing order. Denote by $a_{j k}$ the number in $j$-th row and $k$-th column. Suppose $b_{j}$ is the maximum possible number of entries that can occur as $a_{j j}, 1 \leq j \leq n$ Prove that
> $$
> b_{1}+b_{2}+b_{3}+\cdots b_{n} \leq \frac{n}{3}\left(n^{2}-3 n+5\right)
> $$
> (Example: In the case $n=3,$ the only numbers which can occur as $a_{22}$ are $4$,$5$ or $6$ so that $ b_{2}=3.)$

**My solution**-

I applied Induction on this problem and it reduces to proving that

$b_{k+1}\leq k^2-k+1$

But it follows directly from the fact that $b_{k+1}=1$ because $a_{k+1,k+1}$ has only one option i.e it has to be $(k+1)^2$

But I think this is too easy solution for problem $6$, so someone can pls point out my mistake...

Thankyou

Comment: $a_{jj}$ has multiple options. Given example shows $b_2 = 3$ for $n=3$. Try making an actual example table for $n=3$.

Comment: @cosmo5 I have not made that inequality ,it is arised by applying induction hypothesis and then simplifying.

Comment: Your inequality states $b_2 \le 1$ which is clearly false for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Nope only $a_{11}, a_{nn}$ have one option each, for other $a_{jj}$ there are multiple options. Did you check the example already given in question?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} &   &   &    \\ \hline
\color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} &   &   &    \\ \hline
\color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} &   &   &   \\ \hline
\color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} & \color{green}{s} & \color{red}{a_{jj}} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} \\ \hline
  &   &   &  \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l}  \\ \hline
  &   &   &  \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l}  \\ \hline
 &   &   & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{l} & \color{blue}{n^2}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

I indicate the necessarily smaller entries than $a_{jj}$ by $s$ and necessarily larger entries by $l$. The ends of main diagonal are fixed.

It should be clear that on arranging first $j^2$ numbers $(1,2,3,\ldots, j^2)$ until $a_{jj}$ gives its minimum possible value i.e., $j^2$. E.g.,

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{2} &     \\ \hline
\color{green}{3} & \color{red}{4} &     \\ \hline
  &   & \color{blue}{9}  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

While arranging numbers from last $(n^2, n^2-1, n^2-2, \ldots)$  should give maximum possible value

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \color{green}{1} &   &     \\ \hline
  & \color{red}{6} & \color{blue}{7}    \\ \hline
  &  \color{blue}{8} & \color{blue}{9}  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

which would be $n^2 - ((n-j+1)^2-1)$.

Thus $a_{jj}$ can take possible values in the set $${j^2, j^2+1, j^2+2, \ldots, n^2 - (n-j+1)^2+1} $$

whose cardinality is defined as $b_{j,{\text{max}}}$.

Can you proceed from here?